# Border on top of paragraph

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, text-decorations

I am trying to put a line over a paragraph in LaTeX.
I tried this code:

```
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}
\noindent\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\textbf{Text}}}
```

But there is a small space between the line and the paragraph as shown in this image:

[image]

Do you know how I can remove this space between the paragraph and the text?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\textwidth}{2pt}}\par
\nointerlineskip
\noindent\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{\textbf{Text}}}
```